# dlookup between two tables (nested dlookup not working)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've nested two dlookup functions and it doesn't seem to be working. Please assist?
Issue:
Table one contains student grades:

```
----------
Student_ID     Name      Grade
2892838392     Name1      A+
2892838398     Name3      D+
2892838397     Name2      B+
----------
```

Table two contains value conversions between letter grades

```
Grade          Value
A+             100
A              95
A-             90
```

I've written two dLookkup formulas into one query to pull the information.

```
Expr1: DLookUp("[Value]","[Grade_Scale]","[Grade]='TESTGRADE'")
Expr2: DLookUp("[Freshman - English]","[NJAE Applicant - NJAE GPA Calculator]","[ID]= " & [ID])
```

But for some reason when I nest the two inside each other I get an #Error in the view.

```
Student_Points: DLookUp("[Value]","[Grade_Scale]","[Grade]=" & DLookUp("[Freshman - English]","[NJAE Applicant - NJAE GPA Calculator]","[ID]= " & [ID]))
```

Please assist

Comment: why not simply join the 2 tables on Grade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. I think a join is much easier as submitted by kbball and mentioned in the comments, but for future use here is the corrected syntax:

```
Student_Points: DLookUp("[Value]","[Grade_Scale]","[Grade]= '" & DLookUp("[Freshman - English]","[NJAE Applicant - NJAE GPA Calculator]","[ID]= '" & [ID] & "'") & "'")
```

The criteria argument needs single quotes around the values being tested, including the result of the nested Dlookup.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just trying to attach the value to the grade? Why not just use a join? This one would work:

```
SELECT t1.student_id, t1.name, t1.grade, t2.value
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.grade = t2.grade
```

Comment: This also worked - and I'll defer to it... But if someone can help me out here... why should I head towards this method instead of the DLookup???

Answer (score 1):

You can use *SQL* in DLookup:

```
Student_Points: DLookUp("[Value]","[Grade_Scale]","[Grade] = (Select [Freshman - English] From [NJAE Applicant - NJAE GPA Calculator] Where [ID] = " & [ID] & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on the DLookups that work, `[Grade]` is a text field so you need this:

```
Student_Points: DLookUp("[Value]","[Grade_Scale]","[Grade]='" & DLookUp("[Freshman - English]","[NJAE Applicant - NJAE GPA Calculator]","[ID]=" & [ID]) & "'")
```

(enclose the entire second DLookup that replaces TESTGRADE in single quotes)